# AWS SES works on localhost but not on my hosted website

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

So I have my website in AWS hosted and running using Route 53 - S3Bucket (Angular8 as FE) - ElasticBean (Java11/Spring as BE) - RDS (MySQL).

**I can send emails when the app is running on my machine -> but they don't appear in the SES console as sent, but when running my website the emails are not delivered.**

**I already validated my email address in SES.**

**I already validated my website in SES.**

Those are application.proprieties of my Java App:

```
# Email properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=*
spring.mail.protocol = smtp
spring.mail.debug = true;
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true;
spring.mail.properties.smtps.auth = true;


# AWS CREDENTIALS
spring.mail.host=email-smtp.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=AKIA2QVYHK7ZQXAA6Y
spring.mail.password=AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Example of a email method:

```
  // FEEDBACK MESSAGE
    @PostMapping("/email/feedback")
    public void sendFeedbackEmail(@RequestBody EmailStructure emailStructure) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("Sending feedback email...");
        Message msgToUser = new MimeMessage(getSession());
        Message msgToAdmin = new MimeMessage(getSession());
        msgToAdmin.setFrom(new InternetAddress("chittashop@gmail.com", "Chitta Bot"));
        msgToUser.setFrom(new InternetAddress("chittashop@gmail.com", "Chitta Shop"));

        // SEND THE MESSAGE TO YOURSELF
        msgToAdmin.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("chitta.shop@gmail.com"));
        msgToAdmin.setSubject("Feedback Message - " + emailStructure.getSubject());
        Multipart mpAdmin = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart htmlPartAdmin = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPartAdmin.setContent("<div> Hi, <br> <br>You received a feedback message: <b>" + emailStructure.getSubject() +
                "</b>, from " + emailStructure.getEmail() + " with the following message: <br> <br> - <b> " + emailStructure.getMessage() +
                "</b> - <br> <br> <br>Thanks, <br> Chitta Shop Bot </div>", "text/html");
        mpAdmin.addBodyPart(htmlPartAdmin);
        msgToAdmin.setContent(mpAdmin);
        Transport.send(msgToAdmin);

        // SEND THE AUTOMATIC MESSAGE TO THE USER
        msgToUser.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailStructure.getEmail()));
        msgToUser.setSubject("Feedback Message");
        Multipart mpUser = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart htmlPartUser = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPartUser.setContent("<div> Hi, <br> <br> <b>Thanks for the feedback! </b> " +
                "<br> <br> This automatic reply is just to let you know that we received your feedback message and we will get back to you with a response as quickly as possible. <br> " +
                "During 9:00 a.m to 18:30 p.m (GMT) we do our best to reply as quick as we can, usually within a couple of hours. Evenings and weekends may take us a little bit longer. <br> <br>" +
                "If you have a general question about a specific product, you are welcome to browse our FAQ page for more details of all of our features and answers to frequently asked questions. <br> " +
                "<br>If you have any additional information that you think will help us to assist you, please feel free to reply to this email. <br> <br> <b> We look forward to chatting soon! </b>" +
                " <br> <br> Thanks, <br> Chitta Shop </div>", "text/html");
        mpUser.addBodyPart(htmlPartUser);
        msgToUser.setContent(mpUser);
        Transport.send(msgToUser);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you creds are loading on your hosted site? That is the only issue that i can think of. When I run AWS Code from an app on EC2 - such as SES operations, I prefer using:

```
Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
SesClient client = SesClient.builder()
                      .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
                      .region(region)
                      .build();
```

As you can see, using the **EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider** lets you set the creds as environment variables and there are no issues sending email from an app running on an EC2 instance.

Where is your SES Service client being declared in your code?

Comment: I honestly don't have any SES Service declared because from the information I collected when you use AWS credentials in your zone the you can use JavaMail Libraries directly. Am I wrong?

Comment: Okay I think i found it.

Comment: I was running a specific configuration in Email Service that was overriding AWS config.

Comment: When using SES, its better practice to use the Service client in your code. We have a SES V2 Spring BOOT App example here - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app

Comment: Thank you men, although the solution was easy I was not finding it alone. You helped me ! Thanks alot!